# Prevent home button to open new instance of activity

Tags: android, android-launcher, back-stack

The app is set to be the **launcher** and it is in **kiosk mode**.

When starting the device the app is launched as wanted. It consists of multiple activities. First the user gets into a login activity and with logging in a second activity (main) is started. From here the user should only get back to the login by logging out and nothing else (no hardware back button or home button).

Currently, *when the home button is pressed, a new task is started which holds a second instance of the login screen.* I would like to have only **one instance of both activities in one task**.

What I tried:

- set the login screen to single task/ single instance
- try to catch the event of pressing the home button by overriding onUserLeavesHint -> not always fired
- when the second task is started, check in the onCreate of the new (second) login screen which tasks there are and if one tasks already has the main on top. If there is a main, finish the current login activity. (this works, but the solution isn't very nice, as it is confusing to the user when the login screen shortly pops up an suddenly disappears again.)

Answer (score 0):

```
   /*Place following code in onCreate() before setContentView() of your launcher activity
     * Possible work around for market launches. See http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=2373
     * for more details. Essentially, the market launches the main activity on top of other activities.
     * we never want this to happen. Instead, we check if we are the root and if not, we finish.
     */
    if (!isTaskRoot()) {
        final Intent intent = getIntent();
        if (intent.hasCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER) && Intent.ACTION_MAIN.equals(intent.getAction())) {
            finish();
            return;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! That's what I tried in my third attempt. When finishing the activity in the onCreate I get a blinking effect in my main activity. Is it possible to prevent this kind of visual feedback?

Comment: @bys have you tried it before setContentView or super.onCreate()?

Answer (score 0):

To solve this, in your code, where you do the logic for the login, add finish(); (see below)

> private void logIn(){
>
> Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
>
> startActivity(intent);
>
> finish();
>
> }

If the user presses the logout button, start login activity again.